# PHP Chmod function not workiing

Tags: php, file, chmod

Whenever I try to delete a file from my cpanel folder from my webpage using this code

```
$oldFile = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTR(`materialLink`, 27) FROM `documents` WHERE `iddocuments` = '$iddoc'"),0, `materialLink`);

$chmod = "0777";

chmod($oldFile,octdec($chmod));

$oldFile = 'https://www.edutopia.co.ke'.$oldFile;

 if(isset($_POST['Fild'])){
    $msg1 = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("File successfully deleted");</script>';

    $msg2 = '<script type="text/javascript>alert("There was an error deleting that file.");</script>"';

    $tFile= $_POST['Fild'];

    $delFile = "DELETE FROM `documents` WHERE `iddocuments`='$tFile'";

    mysql_query($delFile);
    unlink($oldFile);
    if (mysql_query($delFile)){
        echo $msg1;
    }
  else {
     echo $msg2;
 }
 }
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  chmod(): No such file or directory in /home/edutopia/public_html/fDelete.php on line 8
>
> PHP Warning:  unlink(): Unable to locate stream wrapper in /home/edutopia/public_html/fDelete.php on line 20

Could anyone be in a position to figure out the remedy, please?

Comment: Using @ in `@mysql_result` to suppress errors is the last thing you need.  If there are errors, then you need to handle them, not ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this has to do something with paths as PHP understands them. If you SSH into the box and do:

```
ls -l /home/edutopia/public_html/fDelete.php
```

...does it exist?

Also, check your web root. It might not be `public_html`.

Answer (score 0):

If `$oldFile` refers to a remote file, as per `chmod()` documentation, it will not work:

> **Note:** This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php